# What is difference between creating object using Object.create() and Object.assign()?

Tags: javascript, object-create

Considering following code:

```
var obj1 = Object.create({}, {myProp: {value: 1}});
var obj2 = Object.assign({}, {myProp: 1});
```

Is there any difference between `obj1` and `obj2` since each object has been created in a different way?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Let's compare `obj1` and `obj2` in this code:

```
var target1 = {}, target2 = {};
var obj1 = Object.create(target1, {myProp: {value: 1}});
var obj2 = Object.assign(target2, {myProp: 1});
```

**Prototypical chain**

`Object.create` creates a new object with the specified [[Prototype]], and `Object.assign` assigns the properties directly on the specified object:

```
obj1 !== target1;
obj2 === target2;
```

The prototypical chains of `obj1` and `obj2` look like

```
obj1 --> target1 -->  Object.prototype --> null
obj2 -------------->  Object.prototype --> null
```

**Properties**

`Object.create` defines properties and `Object.assign` only assigns them.

When creating a property, assignments will create it as configurable, writable and enumerable. When defining a property, you can specify those flags, but by default it's not configurable, nor writable and not enumerable.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj1, 'myProp');
  // { value: 1, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false }
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj2, 'myProp');
  // { value: 1, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true }
```

Comment: So, can we say that "create" is sort of for creating an instance of parent class, while "assign" is just for coping properties?

Answer (score 14):

`Object.assign()` provides **shallow copying** (Only properties and methods) and it will override the method and property declared.

while `Object.create()` provides **Deep copying** provides prototype chain.

I have created a whole medium page on exactly how each data type reacts on Shallow copy and Deep copy.

Here is the link: https://siddharthsunchu1.medium.com/copies-of-javascript-shallow-and-deep-copy-ac7f8dcd1dd0

Answer (score 5):

you can also combine them `Object.assign(Object.create(object))` for both shallow and deep copy, they are perfectly valid pattern in ES6.

Comment: Sounds weird but, as an alternative to the `new` operator, I like this technique because it will "type" the resulting JS object. Example:

Comment: const Cat = Object.assign(Object.create(Animal.prototype),
        {
         takeANap: ()=>{ /*Napping code*/ }
        }

Comment: The resulting `Cat` variable will show up as `Cat` type in the debugger and you can also use `instanceof` with it.

Answer (score 0):

As @emekaokoli mentioned, you can combine

Like this:

```
const el = Object.assign(document.createElement("div"), {
    className: "hello",
    innerHTML:`
      <i>hello world</i>
    `,
    myProp:1
});
document.body.append(el);

console.log(el.myProp);
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vir2alexport/962r4sh3/)

Answer (score -5):

we can also create deep copy of object like this

```
var obj = {id:1, fname:'sajid', lname: 'imtiaz'};
var deepObj = Object.assign({},obj)
```

`